# In Sublime Text 3, is there a way to use an IP address in a snippet?

Tags: ip-address, sublimetext, code-snippets

I often need to access my own (external) IP address in a snippet. It would be great if there was a way to automatically fetch it and include it. Perhaps it can fire a script automatically? I can't find any documentation on this, if it's even possible.

Here's the snippet as it stands:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
if(\$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="${1:87.81.234.232}")echo("<pre>".htmlentities(print_r(${0:var},true))."</pre>");

]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>prjm</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: will be excellent if possible shellcmd here) I wait an answer) [Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2502) something about python addon

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [String Utilities](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/StringUtilities) package

Edit: Sorry, can't be used in a snippet, but it might be worth it taking a look at the plugin source